# Phone signaling encryption

Tags: security, voice

If we encrypt the signaling between the phones and call manager but not the voice packets, can the call still be intercepted, reassembled and listened to?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the voice (also called the "bearer") traffic is unencrypted, it can  be recovered and decoded.  There are lots of tools to do that.

Signalling traffic flows between the Call Manager an phone (or gateway), while bearer traffic flows directly between phones (or phones and gateways).  They are two separate communication streams.